# NoSuchMethodError on Future Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

The error I am getting is The following

> NoSuchMethodError was thrown building QuizPage(dirty, state:
>   _QuizPageState#204c3): The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:   User-created ancestor of the
>   error-causing widget was:    FutureBuilder
>   file:///C:/Users/Prek

It says the error causing widget is the future builder. Below is the code:
[image]

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Please post the code directly and not a picture. Makes it easier to test for errors.

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.data` can be `null`. First check if the snapshot has data using `snapshot.hasData` and then you can use the data:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
 // now you can use snapshot.data
} else {
 // show loading indicator
}
```

Comment: `return FutureBuilder( 
     future:
      DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: true),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        final List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // uncompleted state
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        else {
          return QuizPage(mydata: mydata);
            }
           },
    ); `

Comment: That was the new code but when I run it it shows the loading indicator. This means that the snapshot has data right? What do I do next?

Comment: But if I reverse the conditions in the if and else blocks and run the code, the error still persists.

Comment: oops, you're right! I misplaced the comments. you could print out the snapshot.data to see if you're indeed getting a json string back.